# Fix QToolButton icon

Tags: qt, qaction, qtoolbutton

I have `QToolButton` with a couple `QAction`s inside it.

The problem is that I've set an icon for this toolbar button and I don't want it to change, when I'm selecting some `QAction` (it changes set item to the text from selected `QAction`) from popup menu.

Is there any qt-way to get what I need?

**header file**

```
#include <QToolButton>

class FieldButton : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FieldButton(QWidget *parent = 0);
};
```

**cpp file**

```
 #include "fieldbutton.h"

FieldButton::FieldButton(QWidget *parent) :
    QToolButton(parent)
{
    setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),
                     this, SLOT(setDefaultAction(QAction*)));
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
FieldButton *fieldButton = new FieldButton();
QMenu *allFields = new QMenu();
// ...  filling QMenu with all needed fields of QAction type like:
QAction *field = new QAction(tr("%1").arg(*h),0);
field->setCheckable(true);
allFields->addAction(field);
// ...
fieldButton->setMenu(allFields);
fieldButton->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
fieldButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/field.png"));
fieldButton->setText("My text");
fieldButton->setCheckable(true);
toolbar->addWidget(fieldButton);
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to setup the QToolButton and the QAction's inside it?

Comment: Maybe you can override the button's icon with a custom stylesheet? Take this for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573944/change-icon-on-state-change-using-qt-stylesheet

Comment: @alediaferia I've provided code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I dug a little in the `QToolButton` source code [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtoolbutton.cpp#n453) and it looks like this behavior is hardcoded in the sense that the `QToolButton` class listens for the action `triggered` signal and updates the button default action accordingly ([QToolButton::setDefaultAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#setDefaultAction))

You can probably connect to the same signal and reset the QToolButton icon at your will.

*BTW this looks a rather sensible behavior given that your actions are checkable and wrapped within a QToolButton.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible as alediaferia suggest, you can save the QToolButton icon first and reset it again:

```
 QObject::connect(this, &QToolButton::triggered, [this](QAction *triggeredAction) {
        QIcon icon = this->icon();
        this->setDefaultAction(triggeredAction);
        this->setIcon(icon);
 });
```

PS: if you want to use my code don't forget to enable c++11 support for lambda expression in your pro file by adding CONFIG += c++11